# Dash.js Fullscreen mode

Tags: fullscreen, dash.js

I have a video of not very good quality. The display comes with dash.js. When I select the fullscreen option, it expands to full screen and looks blurry. I need it to add margins on the edges when displaying video on fullscreen.

I'm using dash.js.

Im searching method or options, that can set video ratio in dash.js fullscreen mode.

Thanks for answers.